# ArcGIS for Server Printing - Data Frame Grid

Tags: arcgis-server, printing

We need to print the map from web client (Developed using ArcGIS JavaScript API). I have prepared the Templates and published as Export Web Map (GP Tool). My templates are using Data Frame Grid (Measured grid). I need to customize the grid size based on the printing scale. Is there any possibility of sending the grid size and scale as parameters to Export Web Map tool while generating the print?

please suggest if there is any Paid / Free tools available for printing the data frame grid dynamically on ArcGIS server.